# Synchronize data across all web users

Tags: javascript, html, sql, sql-server

I have a website with a rational DB (SQL SERVER).
I have a table that have 100,000 (not exactly) records across 20 columns.
On my site, there is a page that you can see the table (with pagination, sorting and filtering), 100 records at a time, all fields are editable.
Changes are made about every second, how can I keep the table In sync per client, including sorting, filtering, page number? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you saving edited things to database again??

Comment: In what is your backend written?

Comment: MVC4, and yes, all changes are saved via restful API

Answer (score 0):

Have you consider using **WebSockets**? They are a great way of pushing real-time notifications to browser clients. I haven't worked with MVC4 but I found this link which may shine a light over the idea: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2012/07/17/building-real-time-web-apps-with-asp-net-webapi-and-websockets.aspx.

WebSockets helped me when I had to sync data between browsers.

The idea is pretty simple. On the server-side you will have a handler which will broadcast data over to all client listeners. On the client side you will send to the `WebSocket` handler your new data, at that time the `WebSocket` handler will broadcast that data to all clients and your tables will be in sync. But be careful with your requests and how they are send. You can flood your server if you send a new request on every `keyup` event or smth. But this is another issue.

Here is a [video](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/building-an-html5-web-sockets-server-with-asp-net-4-5) tutorial I just found

Hope this helped you.

**Cheers!**

Comment: I have a socket library but I can't let the users refresh the whole table every second (As I said, the table updates every second)

Comment: You don't have to refresh the whole table. Just the rows that are modified. You can assign a generated UUID id for each cell or column or row and update them individually.

Comment: I don't know how many users or how much editing will be done at once. I'm guessing a user only works on a few cells at once. This way you can update parts of the table as they are being updated. It's not an easy logic to implement this but I think it could do the job right with a WebSocket backing them up.